# Unreachable Code using Arrays, Can't figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort, unreachable-code

So i'm doing a lab for my computer programming class on Arrays using Bubble Sort. Anyways the code is done and should work but one part is getting an error of 'Unreachable Code' and I have no idea why. I can't see the issue here. Here's the full code so you can identify the issue.

```
public class MClab22
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] houseNums = {23, 76, 15, 47, 14, 38, 52};
    System.out.print("The original sequence is: \n     ");
    for (int i = 0; 1 < houseNums.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(houseNums [i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    SortEm(houseNums);
  }
  private static void SortEm (int [] ar)
  {
    int temp;
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; 1 > 0; i--)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
        if (ar[j] > ar[j + 1])
        {
          temp = ar[j];
          ar[j] = ar[j + 1];
          ar[j+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.print("The new sequence is : \n   ");
    for (int i=0; 1 < ar.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print (ar[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

The issue of the 'Unreachable code' occurs at line 29 and is the part that says "System.out.print("The new sequence is : \n   ");"
Please help if you can, thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: your outer most loop condition is: `1 > 0` <- 1 will allways be bigger than 0 and therefor this is an endlesss loop. Did you mean `i > 0` by any chance?

Comment: `for (int i = ar.length - 1; 1 > 0; i--)` you'll never leave this loop

Comment: Your loop is infinite.

Comment: This isn't good either: `for (int i=0; 1 < ar.length; i++)`. I think you mean `for (int i=0; i < ar.length; i++)`.

Comment: A combination of this worked, mostly. Still had one issue but the chosen Answer successfully fixed it. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
public class MClab22{

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        int[] houseNums = {23, 76, 15, 47, 14, 38, 52};
        System.out.print("The original sequence is: \n     ");
        for (int i = 0;i < houseNums.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.print(houseNums [i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        SortEm(houseNums);
      }
      private static void SortEm (int [] ar)
      {
        int temp;
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
          {
            if (ar[j] > ar[j + 1])
            {
              temp = ar[j];
              ar[j] = ar[j + 1];
              ar[j+1] = temp;
            }
          }
        }

        System.out.print("The new sequence is : \n   ");
        for (int i=0; i < ar.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.print (ar[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }

}
```

There are actually 3 problems. The first problem was the loop with condition 1>0. This one  is always true. The other 2 problems were that you have loops with condition  1 < ar.length which is also infinite

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I don't know why it worked but it did lol

Comment: I added the differences sorry

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code):

> In computer programming, unreachable code is part of the source code
>   of a program which can never be executed because there exists no
>   control flow path to the code from the rest of the program.

This part causes problem:

```
for (int i = ar.length - 1; 1 > 0; i--)
```

especially:

```
1 > 0
```

Since it is always true, you have an infinite loop and execution will never reach:

```
System.out.print("The new sequence is : \n   ");
```

Comment: There are 2 more infinite loops though

Comment: Yes, they are, but compiler is sequential, so it will fail on first issue it finds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

and not

```
for (int i = ar.length - 1; 1 > 0; i--)
```